# AngularJS directive templateUrl doesn't update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a problem with angular directives. When I edit the content of a file referenced via `templateUrl`, the result doesn't appear until I delete the cache.  I have the following code:

Directive.js

```
.directive('appMainsec',['$window', function ($window){
    var objectMainSec = {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'partials/app-mainsec.html',
        controller: function (){},
        controllerAs: 'MainSectCtrl',
        link: function ($scope,elemnt,attr){
            elemnt.css('height', ($window.innerHeight - ($window.innerHeight * .25)) + 'px');
        }
    };

    return objectMainSec;
}]);
```

app-mainsec.html

```
<div><h1>Principal</h1></div>
```

and index.html

```
...
 <div app-mainsec></div>
...
```

When I change `<h1>Hi</h1>` to `<h1>Hello</h1>`, the view of directive doesn't update until I delete the cache.

Comment: I cant make out what you're trying to achieve here, where is your controller and your bindings for the <h1> ?

Comment: It isn't a problem, that's how Angular works.  If you want Hi to be Hello create a scope variable and put it on your template.

Comment: You don't need to change title with "(Solve)", if you accept the answer people will see that's solve.

Comment: @jcubic ok, I'm new for here. thanks again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for that is that Angular fetch a file only once at the begining. You can try to use templateUrl as function and append timestamp so you get new template url each time.

```
templateUrl: function() {
    return 'partials/app-mainsec.html?' + +new Date();
}
```

But probably, it will refresh your directive only when directive will be compiled.

Comment: It's worth noting that this will disable browser caching of that html file.

Comment: @JonSnow if cache is needed then there no way without using a server. You will need to watch a file for changes and send notification (you can use websockets) and then updated the date in templateURL. But I don't think something like this is needed, because something like this is only for development. When app is ready he can replace function with a string.