# AngularJS templateUrl not getting refreshed, always uses the cached version

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, caching, angularjs-directive

```
app.directive('myDirective',function() {
    return {
         restrict : 'A', 
         templateUrl : 'app/html.html'
       };
});
```

I'm running into a problem with template html getting cached in the internet explorer. Every time the html is changed, either one of these need to be done to load the new templete:

1. Delete browsing history and clear temporary internet files.
2. Change browser setting 'Check for newer versions of stored pages' from Automatic to 'Every time I visit'

A similar problem is stated [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577945/angularjs-directive-templateurl-doesnt-update). The marked answer works, but was thinking if there is any better solution to the problem rather than defeating the browser caching.

Answer (score 2):

You must use app version and increase after each update:

```
<html data-ver="1.0">
```

And in your js code:

```
// for example: read app version from data-ver attribute on html tag
window.appVersion = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')).attr('data-ver');

app.directive('myDirective',function() {
    return {
         restrict : 'A', 
         templateUrl : 'app/html.html?v=' + window.appVersion
       };
});
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way than to use a cache buster url parameter? I wanted to avoid making a change to all directive declarations

Comment: You can use $templateCache too

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with changes that I made to my templates. I was able get rid of the single template file that I needed to by following these steps:

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Click the **Tools** (Alt-X) button and then click **Internet Options**
3. Click the **General** tab, and then under **Browsing history**, slick **Settings**
4. In the **Temporary Internet Files and History Settings** dialog box, click **View Files**
5. Locate the template file that you have modified and delete it.

I hope this helps.